# Group By in SQL Server , filtering result only referring to one field

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have following query :

```
SELECT st.np_trxn_dt           AS transactiondate,
       st.trxn_dt,
       (
           SELECT ISNULL(st.cheque_no, '-') + '-' + ISNULL(st.bank_name, '-') + 
                  '-' + ISNULL(st.voucher_no, '-') + '-' + ISNULL(st.trxn_by, '-')
       )                       AS OldDescription,
       ISNULL(
           (
               SELECT dbo.bank_statement_remarks(
                          st.bank_name,
                          st.trxn_by,
                          st.sav_amt,
                          st.wthdrl_amt,
                          ISNULL(
                              (
                                  SELECT NAME
                                  FROM   mem_group_mcg
                                  WHERE  group_id = sa.center_id
                              ),
                              ''
                          )
                      )
           ),
           ''
       )                       AS DESCRIPTION,
       (st.sav_amt)            AS Saving,
       st.wthdrl_amt           AS Withdrawl,
       ISNULL(st.remarks, '')  AS remarks,
       st.trxn_dt
FROM   dbo.sav_transaction     AS st
       INNER JOIN (
                SELECT DISTINCT acc_no,
                       center_id,
                       group_id
                FROM   sav_acc_mcg
                WHERE  scheme_id = '100'
                GROUP BY
                       acc_no,
                       center_id,
                       group_id
            ) sa
            ON  st.acc_no = sa.acc_no
WHERE  (st.trxn_dt BETWEEN '2013-07-17' AND '2014-01-22')
       AND st.acc_no = '100-002703'
ORDER BY
       st.trxn_dt
```

Results :
[image]

But I need to filter/group by only trxn_dt/transactiondate,if I add GROUP BY clause, all the fields need to be added to the clause which doesn't give desired results. I need the sum amount according to trxn_dt. I need one row for one trxn_dt per trancaction type , i.e.Deposit or Withdraw.If there are 3 transaction of deposit on same date, then I need one summed row for the transaction, and if there are 2  transaction of withdraw on same date, then I need one summed row for the transaction.
In other words, I need separate rows for Deposit and Withdraw but the results should be the summed.

Comment: Use `SUM(Deposit)` or `SUM(Withdraw)` at your query

Comment: If I use SUM, then GROUP BY clause should be added, this is not the requirement.

Comment: For each column, either all values are the same across the rows you want to combine (in which case adding them to the `GROUP BY` clause should not be an issue) or the values are different, in which case you need to indicate which aggregate function (e.g. `MIN()` or, as with the amounts, `SUM()`) should be used to combine those multiple values into a *single* output value. What's the problem?

Comment: In almost of the cases. the amount and date will only vary but other fields have same values.

Answer (score 1):

Are you trying to filter or are you trying to group? Grouping will only make sense if you are using an Aggregate function (which i dont see in the query you posted). If you want your results summed based on the the transaction date, you anyways wont be able to accomodate other information like cheque number etc. in one row since there will be multiple cheques.

Comment: I just want to filter.

Comment: Can any thing be be on the query to get desired results ??

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
SUM(Deposit) OVER(partition by transactiondate) as totaldeposit
```